# SQL Server database restoration error

Tags: sql-server

Let me explain the issue briefly: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with a database `portaluser2`. I have created another database `chandigarh`.

I took a backup of database `portaluser2` and tried to restore it to database `chnadigarh`. But at time of restoration I am getting an error shown below. Kindly keep in mind that I want both my databases online and running. Kindly assist if anyone have any idea on this.

> Error:  TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore failed for Server '64.31.20.2,7426'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'chandigarh' database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: can you show us your RESTORE comamnd ?

Comment: I restored graphically. Using sql server management studio.

Comment: Selected Database > right click > Tasks > Restore > databases > Selected source and destination > clicked OK to restore

Comment: @TT thanks for editing

Comment: Make sure you tick the "overwrite database" box if you are trying to restore a database that isn't a backup of the target database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can better use the command like this

```
RESTORE DATABASE Chandigarh
FROM DISK = 'c://.../backup.bak'
WITH REPLACE
```

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>RESTORE DATABSE chandigarh FROM DISK = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\portaluser2.bak WITH REPLACE
'RESTORE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: database name is "chandigarh" you can see the same in error.

Comment: Oh no. I am talking about the word after RESTORE. You have written databse.

Comment: This is supposed to be executed in SQL management studio not on the command line